# How to implement markdown2 in the template tags? Getting TemplateSyntaxError 'md2' is not a registered tag library

Tags: django, django-templates, tags, markdown

I followed instructions at [this source](https://pypi.org/project/django-markdown2/) for getting markdown2 to work in the template tags.  The code is below.

`settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'wikiencyc',
    'markdown2',
]
```

Note: I tried using the originally suggested `'django_markdown2'` above but the Django server would not start and give a chain of exceptions originating with the following error:

```
'<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
from line 200 in Python38-32/lib/pathlib.py
```

With `'markdown2'` instead of `'django_markdown2'`, the server started.

`entry_detail.html`:

```
{% load md2 %}
<h4>{{ entry.subject }} </h4>
<br><br>
<p>
    {{ entry.content|markdown:"safe" }}
</p>
```

So, I have tried to do everything according to book. I also made sure that `markdown2.py` is in the path.

I am not sure what they mean by putting `django_markdown2` in the PYTHONPATH. Such an environment variable does not exist on my system.  I tried creating said env variable and putting the value of `django_markdown2`, but still no joy.

I am using Windows 7 as OS, Python version 3.8, and Django version 3.0.8. Below is the output of `pip freeze`:

```
asgiref==3.2.10
cachelib==0.1.1
click==7.1.2
Django==3.0.8
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Session==0.3.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
markdown2==2.3.9
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Pillow==7.2.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
pytz==2020.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
sqlparse==0.3.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

I get the following error.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /wikiencyc/entry/9
'md2' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
```

What am I doing wrong?  Please provide the specifics: which file to edit, what libs to use or import, and exactly what to type, the exact syntax, and where.  The devil is in the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you've actually *installed* `django-markdown2`: it doesn't appear in your `pip freeze` output. It sounds like you've tried to manually download the file and modify your `PYTHONPATH`, but there should be no need to do that.

I hope you are explicitly defining your dependencies, in which case you could add `django-markdown2` to your `requirements.txt` and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. If not, please consider starting this practice.

If you just want to install `django-markdown2` in your current environment, run

```
pip install django-markdown2
```

and forget about manually downloading anything or modifying `PYTHONPATH`.

Hopefully this is with in a virtual environment.

Then, once you've installed the library, change your `settings.py` to include `django_markdown2` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of `markdown2`.

Comment: Thank you Chris.  Now it works:)  I realize the core of the misunderstanding is the very unintuitive need to have 2 seperate packages of django_markdown2 and markdown2.  Common sense would imply one package being included in the other.  Markdown2 without tag functionality substantially limits its utility.  I will ask the said sources to update their info to point out that at this time django_markdown2 and markdown2 are seperate packages and each have to be installed seperately.  Also there is no need to alter the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @EdKideys, [`django-markdown2` depends on `markdown2`](https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-markdown2/blob/8b1a8a2d33be2c32b7f01095a8510882339eae60/setup.py#L29). Just doing `pip install django-markdown2` should install both packages. I'm not sure why the installation instructions focus on manually downloading the files.

Comment: Many thanks for that. I notıced that on installation the package has a dash '-' instead of underscore '_' as depicted on INSTALLED_APPS.  Does it make a difference on installation?

Comment: @EdKideys, no, that doesn't make a difference. That substitution is part of [package name normalization](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/#normalized-names).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is supposed to be

```
'django_markdown2',
```

Instead of

```
'markdown2',
```

In settings.py

This is the same for Adding it to the path